# PHP regular expression with overlapping capture groups

Tags: php, regex

I'm building a "mention" detector. Mentions take the form of `@(user:\d+)`, e.g. `@user:5`.

I would also like to capture the surrounding context, let's say up to five words before and after the mention. I initially went with

```php
$before = '((?:\S+\s+){0,5})';
$mention = '@(user:\d+)';
$after = '((?:\s+\S+){0,5})';
$pattern = "/{$before}{$mention}{$after}/';
```

This works well, except when there is a mention within either of the before or after groups. For instance,

```
Here is some text with @user:123 and @user:456 mentions
```

should return two matches, however `preg_match_all` is only returning the first:

| Before | Mention | After |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `Here is some text with` | `@user:123` | `and @user:456 mentions` |
| `some text with @user:123 and` | `@user:456` | `mentions` |

Is there a way to do this with one pass?

Or alternatively if I have to find just the mentions and their positions with e.g.

```
preg_match_all('/@(\w+:\d+)/', $text, $mentions, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

and then loop through again to get context for each single mention, how can I get the "before" context without again matching on a mention?

Comment: `preg_match_all()` will not return overlapping matches.

Comment: Just match the mentions. Use the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag to get the position in the string. You can use the offset to find the 5 words before and after the match.

Comment: Another option is to not use a regexp at all. Use `explode()` to split the input into words. Loop through the array looking for mentions. When you find one, use `array_slice()` to get the slice from index-5 to index+5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to obtain overlapping matches using a capture group inside a lookahead assertion: `(?=(...))`. But in your case it isn't possible to use this trick because when two mentions are near the start of the string, their "before contexts" start at the same offset 0.

You can split the entire string into "words" (non-spaced characters sequences), and add a marker to the branch that matches the mentions. This way, `preg_match_all` returns a sub-array already filtered with only the mentions indexes.
Then, as suggested in comments, you can use `implode/join`, `array_slice` and basic maths to build the contexts.

```
$text = 'Here are @user:123 and @user:456 mentions';

$contextSize = 5;
$pattern = '~ @user:[0-9]+ \s* (*:mention) | \S+ \s* ~x';

$results = [];

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches)) {
    
    foreach ($matches['MARK'] as $k => $v) {
        $beforeIndex = max(0, $k - $contextSize);
        $beforeSize = $k - $beforeIndex;
        $afterIndex = $k + 1;
        $results[] = [
            'before' => join(array_slice($matches[0], $beforeIndex, $beforeSize)),
            'mention' => $matches[0][$k],
            'after' => join(array_slice($matches[0], $afterIndex, $contextSize))
        ];
    }
}

print_r($results);
```

Feel free to add `rtrim` to delete trailing spaces.

[demo](https://3v4l.org/lPIhs)

Note that `array_slice` deals itself with indexes and lengths that exceed the size of the array without errors or warnings. That's why there's no need to check if there're words (and how many) after the mention before using it.

Comment: Nice workaround for the completely overlapping match.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for the tip about the marker in a regex! Very interesting feature :-)

Comment: @PatrickJanser: obviously you can do the same with a capture group, but you need to use `array_filter` to remove empty indexes after.

Comment: Amazing. Had no idea about markers. Do you know of any good docs on this?

Comment: Found it in PCRE docs. https://pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC27
`(*:NAME)` is a shorthand for `(*MARK:NAME)` to record which match path was taken.